# Roots of $z^4+iz+1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Show that $f(z)=z^4+iz+1$ has exactly one root in each quadrant.

Approach: If $z_0$ is a root, I deduced that $-\bar{z}_0$ is also a root. So if we have for example a root in the first quadrant, we also have one in the fourth quadrant. So it is enough to show that there are two roots in say two different quadrants.
Then I used rouché's theorem to conclude that the roots are in between $1/2 < |z| < 2$. But I'm not sure how to proceed, i.e. how to show that there are in in two different quadrants is a solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure that no root path of $z^4+i\lambda z+1$ crosses the coordinate axes for $λ\in[0,1]$

And indeed for the real axis $z=x+i·0$ the real part $$x^4+1$$ will never be zero. For the imaginary axis $z=0+iy$ the real part is 
\begin{align}
y^4-λy+1&=(y^2-\tfrac12)^2 +y^2-λy+\tfrac34
\\
&=(y^2-\tfrac12)^2+(y-\tfrac12λ)^2+\tfrac34-\tfrac14λ^2
\end{align}
which is also always positive as $\tfrac34-\tfrac14λ^2>\tfrac12$.

Thus the single roots of $z^4+1=0$ stay single and in their quadrant for $z^4+iλz+1=0 $ for all $λ\in[0,1]$.

One can formalize these calculations as a winding number argument or Rouché argument with large enough quarter circles.

Comment: Thanks! ${{{}}}$

Comment: Lovely answer, +1